# Closed questions that perhaps shouldn't be

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13930897/823393) that has a (in my opinion - obviously - it's my answer after all) acceptable answer has been closed by a natural vote as *closed as not a real question*. I clearly disagree as I have posted what is (to me) an acceptable answer.

In most cases I would just let it ride but in this case it nags at me. A question has been closed as unanswerable and yet has an answer! I am loath to just *unclose* for my own personal *gain*.

Comment: Can you edit the question to not be a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes - I expect I could but I thought we were trying to get away from a *this is homework - this is not* mentality and attempting to actually answer the question asked - or at least that was my interpretation of dropping the `homework` tag.

Comment: While he could have done a better job with the details like language, it is a specific answerable question and shouldn't have been closed.  Some people just hate homework questions and look to shut them down.

Comment: I don't understand why you would just do that person's homework for them without even asking them what they had tried or where they were stuck.  That doesn't really help them in the long run.  It just makes them dependent.

Comment: I - for one - LIKE homework questions. It exercises the **explain it simply** glands. :)

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain what you did for them. It's just a code dump. That's not going to help anyone

Comment: I'm blown away that someone cleared my reopen vote, guess they were afraid others that didn't think link them might help out.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Or perhaps it went into the reopen review queue and people just didn't think it was a good question that should be reopened.

Comment: I was a PE on EE for many years and fought battle after battle about how we SHOULD answer (but carefully) homework questions. I moved to SO because I failed to get through to them that homework is just as much a revenue stream as any other type of question. I have to say I am disappointed with the response here. My answer was a perfect example of how to respond to homework. *Answer the question with code that will alert their lecturer and thus make sure they add to it*. @BilltheLizard for shame - I did not do their homework, I showed them how to do their homework and forced them to THINK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closed message doesn't say "the question cannot be answered" - it says "the question cannot be *reasonably* answered." Posting an entire block of code (and thus doing his homework for him) is not a reasonable answer by any means. This isn't a site where you can come post an assignment and get the answer, we're here to help with *specific problems*, of which none exist in this question.

You can't have a problem if you haven't done anything yet. That's like calling tech support when you haven't taken the TV out of the box yet.

Comment: I feel we may be revisiting the `homework` debate - for that I am sorry as I am sure it was a long and painful one - but if the issue here is that the question is homework then that is a separate issue. I have provided an answer which demonstrates that to provide a solution to the question asked one must use a depth-4 loop. That is all I meant to demonstrate and I feel I have done so.

Comment: It's not that the question was homework, it's that they provided absolutely no effort at all to solve it themselves. It's perfectly possible to post a homework problem *and* show what you've done so far, explaining why it doesn't work. *Just* posting the problem isn't an acceptable question.

Comment: Ah! Now I see. In that case we should leave this question closed. Sorry for raising the query.